# how insert space my output using python with bs4 and regex

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

at the output of my program: `print(full_box.text.split())`
output:

```
['AwardThousandGroupAnimal', '1º582507Sheep2º424111Horse3º292306Goat4º370802Eagle5º288221Taurus6º', '[sum]95797º', '[mult]703']
```

(I shortened the html to not be long)

```
<thead>
   <tr>
      <th>Award</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>Sheep</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="text-info">6th [sum]</td>
      <td class="text-info">9579</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

how to make the division separate everything by space?
I tried to make the expression but I get an error

```
full_box = re.sub (r '((? <= [a-z]) [A-Z] | (? <! \ A) [A-Z] (? = [a-z]))', r '\ 1', full_box)
```

expected outcome

```
[1st, 5825, 07, Aries, ... 6th '[sum], 9579, 7th [mult],' 703 ']
```

help, pls
thx

Comment: Could you provide an url and maybe som details, what you try todo, please.

Answer (score 1):

Would it not be simpler to extract the text in your expected outcome as post processing it with the regex?

Based on your example you will get your result as you started:

```
element.text.split()
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<thead>
   <tr>
      <th>Award</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>Sheep</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="text-info">6th [sum]</td>
      <td class="text-info">9579</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

soup.text.split()
```

#### Output

```
['Award', 'Sheep', '6th', '[sum]', '9579']
```